# How do I remove anagram duplicates from a list?

Tags: awk, sed, perl, sort

I have a tab-delineated .csv with strings and descriptions. A bit like this:

```
strap   tight
elba    Island
foo     bar
able    Cain
parts   buy
able    Cain
```

First, I'm sorting the file by length of everything before tab:

```
parts   buy
strap   tight
able    Cain
able    Cain
elba    Island
few     many
```

Then, I'm removing exact duplicates:

```
parts   buy
strap   tight
able    Cain
elba    Island
few     many
```

However, I still need to remove *anagram* duplicates — **parts** and **strap** have the same letters. So do **elba** and **able**.

```
parts   buy
able    Cain
few     many
```

And echo a dialog warning... something like:

[image: dupes found]

---

Any thoughts on how to best do that?

**Edit:**

A few answers from below:

- This is for Mac OS
- I only care about $1 matching
- There won't be any capitalization in $1 (but there will be in $2)
- There won't be any repeated letters in $1

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
  # print length+iii before every line
  awk '{printf "%diii%s\n", length($1), $0}' < file.txt > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out file.txt

  # remove exact duplicates
  sort -u < file.txt > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out file.txt

  # remove non-identical duplicates
  # awk '{magic}' < file.txt > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out file.txt
  # varDupeEcho=remainder from above

  # sort by size
  sort -n -r -k1,1 < file.txt > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out file.txt

  #remove lengths
  sed -i "" -E -e 's/^[0-9]+iii//' file.txt

  # warn about duplicates
  osascript -e "display dialog \"Duplicates found!\n\n$varDupeEcho\" --> Result: \{button returned:\"OK\"\}"
```

Comment: Do you only care about $1 or do you want to de-duplicate based on the whole line or what? Do you want the comparisons to be case-sensitive or not?

Answer (score 4):

The general approach to comparing values in any order of their parts is to sort the parts to create the keys for comparison, e.g. using GNU awk for "sorted_in" and a null 3rd arg to split() splitting the string into chars:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
    OFS = "\t"
}
{
    key = ""
    split($1,chars,"")
    for (i in chars) {
        key = key tolower(chars[i])
    }
    print key, $0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -k1,1 -u | cut -f2-
elba    Island
strap   tight
foo     bar
```

You can see what that's doing 1 step at a time to make it clear:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
aprst   strap   tight
abel    elba    Island
foo     foo     bar
abel    able    Cain
aprst   parts   buy
abel    able    Cain
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -k1,1
abel    able    Cain
abel    able    Cain
abel    elba    Island
aprst   parts   buy
aprst   strap   tight
foo     foo     bar
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -k1,1 -u
abel    elba    Island
aprst   strap   tight
foo     foo     bar
```

I see you added a statement to your question that you're on MacOS - OK, just install GNU awk there. You can do the above with other awks but it'd require either spawning a shell to call Unix sort for the key chars on each input line which would be extremely slow (and a bit cumbersome to write) value or you'd have to implement a sort algorithm yourself which would be cumbersome to write and none of that is worthwhile when you can quickly and easily install gawk and then you have it for this and future problems.

Comment: I'm also looking for the _"echo a dialog warning."_

Comment: @αғsнιη I'm just helping the OP do the part they're stuck with which is how to diff strings with characters in different orders, I assume they can easily figure out the rest just like they figured out what they have so far for handling exact duplicates